# How do I get a link in a web viewer to open in WebDirect's parent browser?

Tags: filemaker

Given a layout that has a web viewer on it and uses the "data" protocol to calculate some HTML that contains links, how can I get those links, when clicked, to open in the parent web browser of WebDirect instead of within the web viewer itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to specify the target in the anchor?

Comment: You were close, but it was enough to get me googling. I needed `target="_top"` instead of `_new`. ty.